# how do i do integration between sql server to salesforce

Tags: integration, sql, sqlserver

unable to integration sql server to salesforce

I want to integrate sql server to salesforce and update records in sfdc

Comment: I've taken the liberty to change the tags of your question. Could you please try to select the most appropriate tags when you post new questions ? This will help attract people with the right knowledge to  your question!

Answer (score 8):

There's a number of offerings on the app exchange for connecting SQL server to Salesforce.  One of the well regarded ones is dbamp - there's full details of their offering at:

http://www.forceamp.com/

You could also achieve this via an ODBC driver - again there are a few providers - here's one example:

https://www.easysoft.com/support/kb/kb01050.html

I've also seen that people have achieved this using the free Jitterbit dataloader, but that's not something I've done myself.  There's more information on setting this up at:

http://www.jitterbit.com/Docs/WebHelp/Targets/Connecting_to_MSSQL.htm

There's also an open source offering for SSIS that has a Salesforce connector - I've never used this though:

http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/#!

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the above answer a very good tool which is also open source is Talend that can connect sfdc and SQL servers

http://www.talend.com/products/data-integration

Talend provides outofbox connectors and drivers and you will need to just handle the mappings more like informatica on demand .Informatica is paid tool while basic version of Talend is open source and freely available .

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party with this answer but hope it helps others...

Salesforce - SQL integration has been a key part of my job for the last 9 years for both on premise backups to SQL of Salesforce and SSIS packages to run adhoc / scheduled uploads to  and extracts from Salesforce via SQL / SSIS.

[Relational Junction](http://www.sesamesoftware.com/relational-junction/salesforce-integration/)

...by Sesame Software has been very effective in both roles and comes highly recommended.

I did a review of the alternatives (including DBAmp) 12/18 months ago and still found Relational Junction to have many features which we consider essential that were missing or painfully implemented in other offerings.